# Trigger Animation on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, squarespace

Basically i'd like to trigger this box animation after the user scrolls down by adding a class.

Can't seem to make this work for me, I'm probably doing something fundamentally wrong. Below is my current code, can anyone give me pointers as to what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

**HTML**

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="600px" height="600px" viewBox="0 0 600 600" enable-background="new 0 0 600 600" xml:space="preserve">
    <rect class="box" x="147.297" y="237.162" fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="8" stroke-miterlimit="10" width="305.405" height="125.676"/>
</svg>
```

**CSS**

```
     @keyframes offset{
    100%{
      stroke-dashoffset:0;
    }
  }

.box{
    stroke:transparent;
}
  .box.draw{
    stroke:#202020;
    stroke-width:5;
    stroke-dasharray:910;
    stroke-dashoffset:910;
    animation: offset 5s linear forwards;
  }
```

**jQuery/JS**

```
$(function() {
    var boxDraw = $(".box");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 400) {
            box.addClass("draw");
        } 
    });
});
```

Additionally, how might it be possible to trigger an animation after a certain point in the page, rather than a scroll value? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: A certain point is a scroll value. You can check the offsetTop of the element you want to check and compare it with the current scrollTop, if you want to trigger the animation when a certain element is in sight, but you always end up with a scroll value. Also, you define `var boxDraw = $(".box");` but you apply the class to `box`, not `boxDraw`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Capsule** has figured it out. Your correct JS code:

```
$(function() {
    var boxDraw = $(".box");
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 400) {
            boxDraw.addClass("draw");
        } 
    });
});
```

To trigger the scroll when a certain element is in view, again **@Capsule** has pointed it out but here's the code

```
$(function() {
    var boxDraw = $(".box");
    var boxDrawTop = boxDraw.offset().top;
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        // let's fire up animation when .box is in view

        if ( scroll >= ( boxDrawTop - windowHeight )) {
            boxDraw.addClass("draw");
        } 
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

search for js lib wow.js (in searching engine-text for minimal content here...)